# New table row is not creating using JQuery clone method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in in that table I have a button for adding new row .In that table I want to dynamically add new row when user will click the add row button. I but it is not working. The HTML and JQuery code is there in JSFiddle . Please suggest.

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        @*<td>SR</td>*@
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @*<td>1</td>*@
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="nmbox" /></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="agbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add " onclick="insRow()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
var new_row1 = $('#mytable tr:last').clone();
$('#mytable').append(new_row1);
```

Comment: Have you tried :last-child instead of :last?

Comment: Can you give a complete sample of your code? I resume what little JS code you've shown is in the `insRow()` function? If so, is that function declared in scope of the `window`, or is it inside a jquery `document.ready` event handler?

Comment: What jsfiddle? Nothing shown would suggest a problem without full code context. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes in insRow the two line of JS code is written.

Comment: id selector mismatched $('#myTable tr:last').  caps T

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: Works fine with '#myTable' - did you have a fiddle where it doesn't work?  https://jsfiddle.net/5atgbfoj/

Comment: Voted close: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 1):

1) id selector mismatched  `$('#myTable tr:last').`   caps T

2) id should be unique for each element .

```js
function insRow(){
var new_row1 = $('#myTable tr:last').clone();
$('#myTable').append(new_row1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        @*<td>SR</td>*@
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @*<td>1</td>*@
        <td><input size=25 type="text"  /></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"  /></td>
        <td><input type="button"  value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
        <td><input type="button"  value="Add " onclick="insRow()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanxxx .removed that too @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0):

To add child elements into cloned one without jQuery:

```
 clone = ElementTo.cloneNode();

 while (ElementToBeCloned.firstChild){
     clone.appendChild(ElementToBeCloned.lastChild);
 }
```